# Timer doesn't resume when I go back to the QuizActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

Iam have done an IQ test app.Iam using a timer to calculate the time taken for the completion of questions in the IQTest.When I pause the timer ,I go to Timeplease activity.This is right but when I go back to the test the timer doesn't resume.Also can someone tell how to calculate time taken to answer correct questions only.

This is AgeCalculation.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class AgeCalculation extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_age_calculation);
    mDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
    calage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculateAge);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    category=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.category);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mDate.setOnTouchListener(this);


    calage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calendar now=  Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Year, Month, Day);

            int years = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int months = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int days = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (days < 0){
                months --;
                days +=now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
            if (months < 0){
                years --;
                months +=12;
            }
            String yearsold = years+" YEARS "+months+ " MONTHS "+days+" DAYS"+" "+"OLD";
            age.setText(yearsold);
            if(years>=0 && years<=10)
            {
                opt=0;
            }else if(years>=11 && years<=15)
            {
                opt=1;
            }else if(years>=16 && years<=30)
            {
                opt=2;
            }
            else if(years>=31 && years<=50)
            {
                opt=3;
            }else if(years>=51 && years<=120)
            {
                opt=4;
            }else
            {
                opt=5;
            }
            switch (opt) {
            case 0:
                start=0;
                end=21;
                indtime=10;
                temp=" KIDS";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 1:
                start=21;
                end=38;
                indtime=11;
                temp=" CHILDREN";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 2:
                start=38; 
                end=56;
                indtime=12;
                temp="TEENAGERS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 3:
                start=56;   
                end=76;
                indtime=11;
                temp="ADULTS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 4:
                start=76;  
                end=99;
                indtime=13;
                temp="ELDERS";
                timetotake=600;
                break;
            case 5:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            default:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            }
            category.setText(temp);
            go.setText("GO"+" "+"TO"+" "+temp+" "+"IQTEST");
            }
    });

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongo);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AgeCalculation.this, QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


}); 
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(
                this, DateSetListener, Year, Month, Day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        Year = year;
        Month = monthOfYear;
        Day = dayOfMonth;
        String sdate = lp(Day + "", "0", 2)+ " " + montharray[Month] + " " + Year;
        mDate.setText(sdate);

    }

};

 private  String lp(String sc, String sp, int len) {
        String sr = sc;
        for (int i = sr.length(); i < len; i++) {
            sr = sp + sr;
        }
        return new String(sr);
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    return false;
}
}
```

This is QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
     pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
     pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
             customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,Timeplease.class);
           startActivity(i); 
         }
     });
    agecal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalage);
    agecal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,AgeCalculation.class);
            startActivity(i); 
            finish();
        }

}); 
    DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(start);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rde=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if(currentQ.getanswer().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
            }
            if(start<end){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(start);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score);
                b.putInt("time",secs);
                //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getquestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getopta());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getoptb());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getoptc());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getoptd());
    rde.setText(currentQ.getopte());
    start++;
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}
};

}
```

This is Timeplease.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class Timeplease extends Activity {
Button back;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeplease);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonback);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Timeplease.this,QuizActivity.class);
            finish();
        }

}); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
               startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro...it's happening.Iam a new bee so getting a bit stuck.Can you please tell me how could we add only time taken to answer correct questions?

Comment: i can not understand your query can you explain me what you want to say

Comment: By the code written by me I can only determine time taken to answer total questions.But,I want to determine time taken to answer correct questions only.

Comment: then you need to find delay between answer and store it somewhre after total it

Comment: and also another way is  pick a timer
and every user button click make it 0
 so you cat time which is taken by user

Answer (score 0):

put the timer code inside the onResume